# Remove extra white space from first page of SQL Server Reporting Services report

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 (though this seems to be an issue for me in 2005 also).  I have a report that has one page per customer (i.e. paged on customerId).  The odd thing I'm seeing is that the first report (i.e. first page of the report) has a bit of extra white space at the top than the other pages.  In general this seems to occur when you have a title for the report and paging (so that the first page has the title, but each successive page does not).  The report I'm dealing with does not have a title like that, but still has this extra white space.

What I'm wondering is how do I prevent that extra white space on this first page of the report.  How do I make each page of the report identical?

I do not have a header or footer applied to the report either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different causes for extra space at the top of the HTML render of a page in any version of Reporting Services.  There are a couple of tricks to working around this depending upon the cause of the problem:

1. Move the title from the Header to the Body of the report.  If the title is a label, this doesn't always help.
2. If you are using a table, then add a separate row to the header of the table.  This seems to work very well, particularly when you render to Excel.  However, not all report requirements can support this as a solution.
3. In SSRS 2000/2005, if you are using a container such as a rectangle or group, then the odds that you will having a spacing issue increase.  If you can move the title out of the container, then this can help reduce the likelihood of a problem.  I haven't tried using the Tablix grouping controls in SSRS 2008, so I can't tell if this will work in SSRS 2008.
4. If you keep the header and footer objects on even you aren't adding any labels to the regions, then these can lead to extra spaces on the first page.

It is difficult to give you better advice without reproducing your exact problem.  If you want to post the code for a sample RDL file temporarily, then I can try to reproduce the problem in SSRS 2008 on my machine and see if I can provide you with a custom solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found the problem i had with extra space on first page.

In my case, the report has a header (with a textbox inside) and in the body a table.
The problem was that on first page (printed from the app) appeared a little space between the header and the table on the body. Well, apart from that the result was perfect.
But when exporting to Excel, first page only showed header, the rest of the pages looked perfect.

The solution: when you add a table (at least in the body), this table has automatically header and footer. I wasn't using header nor footer so i've removed them (first file and last file of the table) and voilá =-D

that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Reporting Services / SSRS 2008. I have a table (tablix) with column headers and a subreport in the last row. How do I get rid of the extra space on the first page? It looks ugly when exported to Excel. I've tried moving the table immediately below the report header and it does not work. It seems to enforce a tiny space between the two.